# SQL 2008 R2 Standard - Index View Support

Tags: sql-server

Many years ago (almost ten) I thought Index View is more like an enterprise edition (SQL 2000) only feature but I was wrong and Index view were indtroducted in SQL 2000 to satifsy competivive product's support for materialize view.

However, You can still create index view and physically materialize that view in all the edition of SQL 2000/2005 and query will use that index on a view if you specify NOEXPAND query hint (which is not needed in enterprise/developer editon)

Here is the white paper on Index View (that confirm what I said earlier)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921.aspx

However, it appears to me that starting with SQL 2008/R2 index view indeed is an enterprise edition feature.

I did compare feature by different edition 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx

so in SQL 2008 R2 Standard edition you are able to create index view but looks like **NOEXPAND** hint will not work so it is almost useless...

Is it possible to create index view and use that index (instead of index on base table) in SQL Server 2008 R2 (standard or express edition) using noexpand hint?

Comment: What makes you say that the `noexpand` hint won't work? I can't see anything about that in your link?

Comment: Martin, I created a view in standard edition and it is not using noexpand hint and the index on that view. Also, why feature comparision by edition does not mention Index View support in standard editon?

Comment: [This article](http://www.networkworld.com/community/blog/indexed-views-are-good-feature-which-edition?source=nww_rss) seems to confirm that `NOEXPAND` does not work in R2 Standard.

Comment: Joe, I also read that when I googled it... Just trying to find that is someone had similar experience

Comment: Martin and Joe, I think it appears to me that the index view indeed is enterprise only feature. Thank you...

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli: How about writing this up as an answer, just to get this thing cleared up?

Comment: @Christian Severin: As requested, I've made my comment an answer.

Answer (score 2):

[This other article on SQLServerCentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/editions/88074/) seems to suggest that yes, NOEXPAND continues to work perfectly on every edition of SQL Server from 2005 to 2012. I'll quote:

> "Then NOEXPAND hint still works in non-Enterprise editions of SQL Server. I think there has been some confusion as to what this hint actually does. It forces the query optimizer to rely on the view, rather than the underlying table, for optimization. It does not force the query optimizer to use any given index on a view.
>
> The sites I found online stating that NOEXPAND does not work did not include any testing methodology, so I can't say why it did not work for them.I can say that it can work in situations where the query optimizer decides the index is useful."